# How To Generate A Report Of All Messages Triggering A Specific NDR

Tags: linux, centos, scripting, sendmail, shell-scripting

CENTOS 5.x | Sendmail

Hello All,

I hope this is a simple question. =) I need to generate a report summary of messages that triggered a specific DSN code.   For example:

```
Jan 11 07:43:34 server-example sendmail[12732]: p937blksdh3: to=<someuser@recipientdomain.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=102537, relay=mta.recipientdomain.com. [12.34.56.78], dsn=5.7.1, stat=Service unavailable
```

Normally, I would just grep for this information (something like: **grep -i "dsn=5.7.1" /var/log/maillog**).  But the problem is that this only returns a line like above and doesn't tell me the sender of the message.

Ideally, I'm looking for a one-liner that can do the following:

1. Search sendmail maillog for specific DSN.
2. Identify the message-id for the email. (I'm guessing **awk '{print $}'** would be used?)
3. Return the message details for each (presumably grepping for the the message id retrieved from step 2).

I'm a n00b at scripting/one-liners so I'm sure there's probably an easier way to do this.  Any thoughts?

Thanks,

-M

Answer (score 1):

The following will search for your dsn and if it matches dsn=5.7.1 it will print the msg-id and the sender:

```
awk '{if($13 ~ /dsn\=5\.7\.1/)print $11 $7}' < /var/log/maillog
```

I'm not really sure what specific data you're trying to extract other than the msg-id and sender, but you could switch the `print $11 $7` fields ($11 $7) by manually counting the fields delimited by white space to select what you want.

Is this what you were after?

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient (2 scans of the logfile), but should do the trick:

awk '/dsn=5.7.1/ {print $6}' /var/log/maillog|while read ID; do awk "/$ID.*from=/ {print \$7}" /var/log/maillig; done